# What's the relationship between joint distribution function and joint conditional distribution function?

Tags: probability

I'm currently learning Probability theory by myself, and I have some confusions about the relationship between joint distribution function and joint conditional distribution function.

I learnt that $f(x,y)=f_X(x)\cdot f_{Y|X}(y|x)$

So I'm wondering if the joint distribution function and joint conditional distribution function has the same relationship, which is $F(x,y)=F_{Y|X}(y|x)F_X(x)=P\{Y\leqslant y | X\leqslant x\}P\{ X\leqslant x\}$.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Yes.  General definition.  Let $A$ and $B$ be events.  Then $P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$.  In your example $A=(Y\le y)$ and $B=(X\le x)$.

Comment: The notation $F_{Y|X}(y|x)$ is usually used for $P(Y\leq y|X=x)$. Bt it's ok if you clarify that is $P(Y\leq y|X\leq x)$

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: "yes".

By definition we have:$$P(A\mid B)P(B)=P(A\cap B)$$applying that you find that $$P(Y\leq y\mid 
X\leq x)P(X\leq x)=P(X\leq x\wedge Y\leq y)=F_{X,Y}(x,y)$$